# PHP mysql Distinct, only load 1 set of ids

Tags: php, mysql, select, distinct

I'm trying to get data where order doesn't matter with unique ids. So simply my query would be

```
SELECT DISTINCT id1, id2 FROM messages ORDER BY date
```

If i have a database with the following data:

```
id1 | id2 | date
 5  |  6  |  1/2/2011
 6  |  5  |  1/1/2011
```

I would only need to load the column with the newest date because the ids are the same 2 people. Really i have to load ids where one of the ids is yours so my real query right now is

```
SELECT DISTINCT userid_1, userid_2 
  FROM messages 
    WHERE userid_2=$dbid 
    OR userid_1=$dbid 
ORDER BY date
```

and i get a result as `[6 5] [5 9] [9 5] [5 15] [5 6] [5 17]`

Results 2 and 3 are the same and 1 and 5 are the same. Really only 4 results should be queried. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
if(userid_1 >= userid_2,userid_1, userid_2) AS 'id1', 
if(userid_1 >= userid_2,userid_2, userid_1) AS 'id2'

FROM messages 
WHERE userid_2=$dbid OR userid_1=$dbid ORDER BY date
```

1. This query shows two fields for each record.
2. The first field will be userid1 if it is bigger or equal to userid2, else will show userid2
3. The second field has the opposite logic
4. This makes sure that two similar sets of results will alwas be ordered the same way, so the `DISTINCT` will regard it as same.

Comment: For some reason if i do that it loads the correct ammount of rows, but it wont actually get any data. it just shows [][][][] which in those is supposed to show me the ids being loaded.


if($result > 0) {
 while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
  echo "[".$row['userid_1']." ".$row['userid_2']."] ";
 }
}

Comment: nvm, forgot you need to put the [if(userid_1 >= userid_2,userid_1, userid_2)] in the brackets.

Comment: It works perfect, but if you dont mind can you explain to me how that works because im not quite sure i understand it.

Comment: You can add "AS userid_1" and "AS userid_2" after the two `if`s, to "rename" the resulting fields.

Comment: Nice.  Way less convoluted math than mine!

Answer (score 1):

If your goal is to get distinct pairings, you could do the following to get the smaller of the pair always in the left column and the larger into the right, thus ensuring that distinct works:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
(id1 - ( (id1 - id2) + abs(id1 - id2) ) * .5) as first,
(id2 + ( (id1 - id2) + abs(id1 - id2) ) * .5) as second
FROM messages ORDER BY date;
```

Since the pairs are always arranged, no need for any pairing functions.

## Example

```
+------+------+--------+------------+
| id1  | id2  | val    | pair_date  |
+------+------+--------+------------+
|    4 |    5 | test 1 | 2010-12-25 |
|    5 |    4 | test 2 | 2011-10-31 |
|   17 |   50 | test 3 | 2011-07-04 |
|   50 |   17 | test 4 | 2001-01-01 |
+------+------+--------+------------+
```

If I run this query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
   (id1 - ( (id1 - id2) + abs(id1 - id2) ) * .5) AS first, 
   (id2 + ( (id1 - id2) + abs(id1 - id2) ) * .5) AS second 
   FROM pairs ORDER BY pair_date;
```

I get:

```
+-------+--------+
| first | second |
+-------+--------+
|   4.0 |    5.0 |
|  17.0 |   50.0 |
+-------+--------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Obviously using a boolean has the same effect, is easier to read, and probably is faster, but the above algorithm is handy if you just need to swap two numbers so that one side is always the lesser.

I'm not sure why you would have gotten an error.  I'm running my tests directly from the MySQL command line....

Comment: Thanks, i already got it but i put this in to see if it worked also and it made the mysql_num_rows error out. I didn't find which error it is since i already have a working way and i was curious if yours would work too.

The way i ended up doing it was
"SELECT DISTINCT if(userid_1 >= userid_2,userid_1, userid_2), if(userid_1 >= userid_2,userid_2, userid_1) FROM messages WHERE userid_2=$dbid OR userid_1=$dbid ORDER BY date DESC"

Comment: I definitely tested it, because I knew it was kind of weird.  There are a lot of parenthesis, leaving room for confusion.... Also, the values are returned as doubles because of the dividing by 2.  The other thing is that I don't actually have a date field in my test. I don't think that should matter.  I'll add a few and post my test.

Comment: Thanks for trying it out, though, and giving me feedback.  Let me know if it ever works or comes in handy.